# Откуда появились слова "квест" и "импрофест"?

Tags: этимология, заимствования

Здравствуйте! Откуда произошли слова квест и импрофест в русском языке, откуда они заимствованы? Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Это английские слова в начальной стадии заимствования.

**Quest** означает "*поиск*", сейчас в крупных городах получили популярность *квест-игры*, в которых группе участников предлагается решить ряд интеллектуальных заданий, чтобы выбраться из физического замкнутого пространства. Под это обычно оборудуют подвалы (начиналось всё с компьютерных квест-игр).

**ImproFest** - сокращение от *festival of improvisation* (фестиваль импровизации). Суть "импровизации" состоит в актёрской игре без сценария, занимаются этим обычно группы актёров, каждая имеет своё название.

Answer (score 1):

Quest - слово интернациональное, исходно, видимо, латинское, из него перешло во французский, оттуда попало в английский, где и приобрело современное значение (*соискани*е - в качестве одного из возможных), с которым и расползлось по миру.
Тому способствовало широкое распространение компьютерных игр, в которых под "квестами" понимается широкий круг разного рода дополнительных заданий, а иногда и цель самой игры. В русском нет достаточно точного аналога, поэтому слово приняли без перевода.

В отношении Импрофеста. Под ним понимают ***фест***иваль **импро**визированного искусства (а не *импровизированный фестиваль*, как почему-то иногда полагают). Конечно, это образование сначала появилось на английском - от  festival и improvisation. 
Но поскольку в русском исходные слова давно заимствованы без изменения фонетики, а способ образования русского неологизма вполне свойственен русскому языку, то говорить о прямом заимствовании было бы неправильно. Вполне возможно, что само слово можно определить как собственно русское образование, состоявшееся под влиянием английского аналога. Не знаю уж, насколько важно это мое уточнение за пределами чисто академических рассуждений.

Answer (score -1):

Интересно, что у многих исконно русских и славянских слов любят искать корни в других языках. Было бы несправедливо не заметить, что каким-то образом всё-таки находят. Хотя, если присмотреться к русскому языку, а не к латыни и английскому (которые произошли от праславянского, в некотором роде), то слово раскрывается как цветок. Так произошло и со словом "квест". Слово это произошло от достаточно старого на сегодняшний день слова "весть". От него и "Новости" - НОВые веСТИ, и "Невеста" - НЕт ВЕСТочки о замужестве, и "Вестник" - тот, у кого ВЕСТь.
Если рассматривать подобным образом слово "квест", то получится К ВЕСТи. Замечали, участники, принимающие участие в этой игре, бегают от одного места к другому - "От весточки К ВЕСТочке".
Вот и получается, что слово-то наше, родное. И имеет наши корни. 
Если не верите тому, что я написал, попробуйте тогда найти корни у английского и латинского слов. Как они там оказались?